# How i can change MicroSecond ( 1000 ) to minutes in DateTime?

Tags: php, datetime

How i can add minutes to a DateTime() object in PHP?
or
How i can change MicroSecond ( 1000 ) to minute in this code without create another variable

```
$lastUpdateR = new DateTime($lastUpdateR->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.').($lastUpdateR->format('u') + 1000)."Z");
```

Comment: This is a curious piece of code. You are trying to make a DateTime into `$lastUpdateR` ... while using `$lastUpdateR` for the initial value to DateTime. Was `$lastUpdateR` also made before this line of code?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the add function:

```
$lastUpdateR->add(new DateInterval('PT1M'));
```

See [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) for more information on the syntax of the DateInterval.

Comment: is not working inthis situation bcz i want just change .. ($lastUpdateR->format('u') + 1000) ...